# Changing the size of a standard About panel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-lion, about-box

In my app I display a standard About window using the method `orderFrontStandardAboutPanel:`of `NSApplication`.

The panel thus presented has a size of 285x335 pixels. Is there a way to make it bigger?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably read [this article](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000071.php) and [this technote](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2179/_index.html).

You'll want to pay attention to the custom NSView section in the technote because you can't just specify as size for the standard window.  At the end of the day, probably the simplest thing is to just treat it like opening any other window and implement the behavior yourself.

Comment: Consider improving your post since your answer is essentially two links. See: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/156620) and [Why is linking bad?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7515/156620)